# Tex capacity exceeded with back references

Tags: back-referencing, capacity

I am getting an error, `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [text input levels=50]. \backcite {refone}{{1}{1}{section.1}}`, TexStudio points to the `brf` file.

> I suspect the error comes from `\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}`; as it works when I remove `backref=page` from this.

The current file is too big to post here, and I don't know how to write a reasonably short file that generates too many back references.

My question is, how do I increase the limit so that it works with more back references? I looked at the `texmf.cnf` file, but couldn't find any option to increase this limit.

Comment: `<bla><bla>` sounds like TeX got into serious trouble. Honestly, you are using LaTeX for long enough to know that you probably just got a simple typo in your code that lets TeX trip over. A missing brace maybe.

Comment: "text input levels" indicates a bug in the code (you are opening too many files). Look in the log-file if you find a clue. Beside this: It is rather easy to write a loop that creates lots of backcites.

Comment: @Johannes_B I did not copy that part. It is, indeed, `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [text input levels=50]. \backcite {refone}{{1}{1}{section.1}}`. I'll update the question.

Comment: what did you expect `\cite{~\cite{ref}}` to do? Or was it simply a typo?

Comment: as the cause of the problem wasn't shown in the question, and you have added a solution to the question, this question isn't really answerable, do you want to delete it? Or post a self-answer? or?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Just a typo!
OK, I'll post a self answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually, solved the issue. Just in case anyone has a similar problem, the problem was `\cite{~\cite{ref}}` (just a typo).

Comment: Accepted just to remove it from the pool of unanswered questions.